# egrep not working with extended expressions

Tags: grep

I have the code below

```
read searchTitle
read searchAuthor

egrep -iq "^$searchTitle$|^$searchAuthor$" cutText.txt
```

This code is supposed find either `$searchTitle` OR `$searchAuthor` (Exact match) from cutText.txt. The user can either leave `$searchTitle` or `$searchAuthor` blank.

For example, a user can leave `$searchTitle` blank and type in "obiwan" as `$searchTitle`, and the output is supposed to be as shown:

```
Star Wars 1:obiwan
Star Wars 2:obiwan
Star Wars 3:obiwan
```

My cutText.txt contents is shown below.

```
mao:gou
MARY IS A LITTLE LAMB:lol
Star Wars 1:obiwan
Star Wars 2:obiwan
Star Wars 3:obiwan
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! (:

Comment: None of the lines in `cutText.txt` is exactly `obiwan`.

Comment: Oh no... Thanks for pointing it out. I didn't realise that the : is sticking to the word `obiwan` . I will try using `cut` first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you were trying to do is:

```
grep -E -iq "^$searchTitle:|:$searchAuthor$" cutText.txt
```

man grep. egrep is deprecated. Look:

```
$ searchTitle='star wars 1'; grep -E -iq "^$searchTitle:|:$searchAuthor$" cutText.txt; echo "$?"
0
$ searchTitle='star wars'; grep -E -iq "^$searchTitle:|:$searchAuthor$" cutText.txt; echo "$?"
1
$ searchTitle='obiwan'; grep -E -iq "^$searchTitle:|:$searchAuthor$" cutText.txt; echo "$?"
1
$ searchAuthor='obiwan'; grep -E -iq "^$searchTitle:|:$searchAuthor$" cutText.txt; echo "$?"
0
$ searchAuthor='obi'; grep -E -iq "^$searchTitle:|:$searchAuthor$" cutText.txt; echo "$?"
1
```

Comment: Good afternoon to you here from Singapore. I just can't believe the solution was this simple, and yet I spent so much time finding out what is wrong and overthinking it. You have immensely helped me alot along my path to learning bash programming. I have found the entire regex syntax to be extremely confusing and just couldn't figure out how I can just grep either the `title` OR `author`, with countless of hours researching online and confusing myself.  Your comment to the other question is of great help too. I sincerely thank you for your heart to help others along their learning journey.